# When I start a new MVC4 project using the Internet Application template and use NuGet to get JQuery 1.9, I get an error before making any changes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

There's no issue in Chrome or Firefox, but with IE9 I get a "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'live'" exception. Has anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery 1.9 removed methods previously marked as deprecated. [**live()**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is one of them.

When using jQuery 1.9 it is recommended to use `jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js` along with it when upgrading.

The migrate file contains all of the deprecated methods and in addition writes deprecation notices to the console.

In your case off course you are starting a new project but it looks like you would benefit from using the migrate file too as it will let you know if you start using deprecated features.

Have a look at the release notes posted on the jQuery Blog for all the details and instructions:
[**jQuery 1.9 Final, jQuery 2.0 Beta, Migrate Final Released**](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/)

Comment: I think it would be much better to update the code to use the proper methods. But if parts of the ASP.net JS use those deprecated functions that might not be an easy solution...

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Absolutely, use of proper methods is the correct way +1. OP might benefit from the migrate file at this time (specially if ASP.Net has some default code) to see the warnings but off course, the best way in my opinion would be to not use the migrate file and refer to a features jQuery api documentation for ideas first as most documentation will state if it is deprecated/removed and sometimes it also states what methods to use instead. As with `live()` for example in the docs in the header it states `version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9`.

Answer (score 1):

`.live()` is deprecated in jQuery for quite some time now and was removed in 1.9.

Use `.on()` with the proper parameters instead. A drop-in replacement for the deprecated `$('foo').live('evt', func)` is `$(document).on('evt', 'foo', func)`

However, instead of `document` better use something closer to the element that also exists all the time.